# How to run a .jar in mac?

Tags: java, macos, jar

I've written a relatively simple java application. I have JDK on my PC, but I need it to run on a mac for school. The `.jar` runs perfectly on my PC, but I tested it on my Macintosh (which, BTW, does not have JDK installed).

Why isn't it running on mac? How can I fix this? Is fixing it even possible?

Comment: does the mac have a JRE? If no that could be your problem right there. try `java -jar <jar_file>.jar`

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using to build the Jar?  What version of Java is on the Mac?

Answer (score 90):

You don't need `JDK` to run Java based programs. `JDK` is for development which stands for `Java Development Kit`.

You need `JRE` which should be there in Mac.

Try: `java -jar Myjar_file.jar`

EDIT: According to [this article](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/install-java-jre-mac-os.html), for Mac OS 10

> The Java runtime is no longer installed automatically as part of the
>   OS installation.

Then, you need to install JRE to your machine.

Comment: Mac no longer ships the JRE with the OS.  It's installed the first time you try to use it.  I'm not sure if `java` from the command line should do it but regardless there's a good chance it will need to be installed

Comment: @ChrisThompson: Well.. If that's the case. It will need to be installed.. Thanks for update. :)

Comment: @ChrisThompson - What do you mean by "it's installed the first time you try to use it?"

Comment: @ChrisThompson It still comes with max by default.

Answer (score 8):

Make Executable your jar and after that double click on it on Mac OS then it works successfully.

> sudo chmod +x filename.jar

Try this, I hope this works.

Comment: In my case, I also had to add this command on the terminal: java -jar Myjar_file.jar and right after, the installation process will start

Answer (score 0):

I made the jar file executable as indicated by @Java D: `sudo chmod +x filename.jar`, and then I ran from the terminal `Java -jar filename.jar` as indicated in another answer by @Hardik Mishra. The installation process will start right after it.