# How to run jar files in Mac using JRE?

Tags: java, macos

Mac OSX 10.11.14 (El Capatin) does not ship with Java, either the complete development kit (JDK) or the run-time environment (JRE).  My need was to just run a .jar file and not for complete Java development.  So I downloaded the JRE from **[here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)**, which is a much smaller file compared to JDK (quite obviously).

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828076/how-to-run-a-jar-in-mac)** SO answer says that JRE is enough to run jar files.

After installation of JRE I couldn't locate the directory where installation happened or run `java` command to execute files on my mac.  How do I run jar files now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run java application you can either use

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

or (as you found)

`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`

In any case, if you need to run java often, you should set JAVA_HOME in either your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` and amend the PATH to include the bin directory.

Comment: I tried this to add to path:
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin`  but I get an error when I type java to execute files:
`Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/bin/java" (-1)`.  Any suggestion @David?

Comment: @SriramRanganathan you should use `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/`

Answer (score 0):

After JRE installation, the correct path is:

`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin`

But now, how do I run the `java` command? It seems like the java file located in the directory above is not an executable.

Comment: after jre installation, open a new terminal window and type java -jar yourfilename.jar....
jre installation should add jre path to environment variable and you don't need to look for the installation path